# Configure meshlab to convert .x3d to .u3d

Tags: software-installation, compiling, makefile

I am following [this guide](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~stephenh/index.php/2015/08/18/3d-pdfs/) to embed 3d plots from Wolfram Mathematica into a PDF created with latex. The author of the guide is using Ubuntu 15.04 and I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I have my .x3d file, I installed Meshlab with sudo apt-get install meshlab and I downloaded and extracted the .u3d converter from the link given in the guide.

After this point, I have basically no idea of what I am doing, so I start having problems that I don't understand (and therefore cannot solve):

1. The INSTALL file suggests to use ./configure; make; make install. I open the terminal in the corresponding folder. Before ./configure, there are Makefile.in and Makefile.am files. After ./configure, no other Makefile is generated, even though I don't get any error message when running ./configure. So when running make, I get the "no target specified and no makefile found" message.
2. The guide suggests to use cmake-gui. The INSTALL file says that cmake is only mac option for now, but I still give it a try. I open the terminal in the folder containing the folder obtained by extracting the .zip and run cmake-gui name_of_folder. I click on Generate and select the Unix Makefiles as generator, and get an error message: Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid.
3. Despite this error, a folder is generated. I try to continue following the guide (again, without really knowing what I am doing) and try to do make somewhere in the obtained folder. But there isn't any Makefile anywhere.
4. Finally, step 8 of the guide sounds completely obscure to me:

> Go to that directory of build files and do a make;sudo make install.  This should put them in /usr/local/bin, which normally is ok, but meshlab has a hardcoded link to the IDTFConverter in /usr/bin, so I just symlinked it with: ln -s /usr/local/bin/IDTFConverter /usr/bin

I assume that the directory of build files is the one unsuccessfully generated by CMake. Again, no Makefile anywhere. The rest is completely beyond my comprehension.

If anyone sees what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate some hints. If there is no visible mistake, I would like to understand more what I am doing. What are the build files and what are they used for? Why do we want them in /usr/local/bin and what does it mean to symlink?

Comment: What exactly **does** happen when you run `./configure`? Until you get that step to work (and produce a Makefile) there's no point trying the other steps. FWIW I just tried it in a 16.04 VM and it seemed to configure and make OK.

Comment: After a long list of checking, the process ends with this lines:

"checking png.h usability... no

checking png.h presence... no

checking for png.h... no

Install PNG headers"

What are the PNG headers and how do I install them? Is this causing the issue?

Comment: So you will likely need to install a png development package - my system has `libpng12-dev` for example (although `libpng16-dev` is available)

Comment: Thank you very much! I installed libpng16-dev and after the analogous error for jpeg and installing libjpeg-dev, the ./configure generated the Makefile which is now running. Everything seems to be ok, thanks!